# Use IOSTREAM instread of file in Pygmentize

Tags: python, pygmentize

I have following in my Python script:

**What I try to do is**

read a partial source code(e.g. line 20 to line 40) to buffer and pip/apply the IOSTREAM to pygmentize so that I can generate code highlighting for the partial source code.(e.g. line 20 to line 40)

Currently, I create partial tmp file for the partial source code(e.g. line 20 to line 40) and use the tmp file on **pygmentize**.

```
subprocess.call(["pygmentize", "-f", "html", "-o", htmlFile, tmpFileName])
```

`tmpFileName` is the file name for the code that I want to highlight.

**My Question:**

How can I create **IOSTREAM** and **pip/apply** the **IOSTREAM** to **pygmentize** so that I don't have to create tmp file in /tmp directory

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: why do you do it as a proc call instead of doing it in python? http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/

Comment: This is very question, I did not realize there is highlight() function that you can do that.